# Rails 4 View and Update all form for has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and am currently working on a simple attendance database. Initially I used a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, but because I now need to track additional information and update all records quickly, I'm replacing it with a has_many through model.

Declarations currently look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :events, through: :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :registrations
 has_many :users, through: :registrations
end
```

Registration also has a 'status' string field to allow for 'Yes', 'No' and 'Maybe' responses.

I'm currently trying to build a form cycling through all events, with each event displaying all users and their responses so far. Like so:

```
Event 1
John  Yes()  No()  Maybe()  No Response(*)
Anne  Yes(*)  No()  Maybe()  No Response()
Mike  Yes(*)  No()  Maybe()  No Response()

Event 2
John  Yes(*)  No()  Maybe()  No Response()
Anne  Yes()  No()  Maybe(*)  No Response(*)
Mike  Yes()  No()  Maybe(*)  No Response(*)

Event 3
John  Yes()  No()  Maybe()  No Response(*)
Anne  Yes()  No()  Maybe()  No Response(*)
Mike  Yes()  No()  Maybe()  No Response(*)

[Submit]
```

When I was built it based on a single response using HABTM, as simple_form took care of it with just 'f.association', but I'm not even sure where to begin here with my controllers and views.

Appreciate any responses, even just tips in the general direction I want to be heading.

Comment: Look into nested attributes. There's a railscast for it too.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the revised nested attributes railscast is behind a paywall and knowing how to update depreciated examples is a bit difficult for a rails newbie.

Comment: maybe this link will help you http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a State Machine
2. Access Through

---

**State Machine**

Just saw you had this setup (but I'll keep in because I'm already writing)

You *may* benefit from a [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). This basically allows you to have a single column (called `state` or `status`), and will update its value with a set of user-defined methods:

```
    #app/models/registration.rb
state_machine :initial => :maybe do

    #States
    state :no
    state :yes
    state :maybe

    #Attend
    event :will_attend do
        transition :all => :yes
    end

    #No
    event :will_not_attend do
        transition :all => :no
    end

end
```

This maybe over the top for your use, but will hopefully give some insight into what you can do

---

**Access Through**

The real answer to your question is to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) or access the `join model` directly:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :events, through: :registrations
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :registrations
 has_many :users, through: :registrations
end

#config/routes.rb
resources :events do 
   get "register", to: "registrations#new" #-> app/events/:event_id/register
   post "register", to: "registrations#create" #-> app/events/:event_id/register
end

#app/controllers/registrations.rb
def new
     @registration = Registration.new
end

def create
     @registration = Registration.new(registration_params)
end

private

def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:status).merge({user_id: current_user.id, event_id: params[:event_id]})
end

#app/views/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @registration do |f| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status,  "Yes" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, "No" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, "Maybe" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what the scaffold generated (aside from the updated routes) for my registration join table. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem of generating a registration form matrix with all events and all users to quickly update everything.